# Can I deploy a configuration file along with the generated jar in Maven

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, artifactory, dropwizard

I have a DropWizard Java project, which builds a Shaded Jar when I run `mvn package`. I have this project being build through TeamCity, and deployed the generated Jar+Pom to Artifactory.

To run this project, I need a configuration Yaml file. This file does not get deployed to artifactory right now.

**Question**: Is there a way to add a step in POM to through out the config file along with the jar and pom so that teamcity can deploy that to Artifactory aswell?

Currently the only way I see of accomplishing this is by adding the path to config file in the Teamcity "include" section. However, this overwrites the default includes: the resulting files from mvn package.

I tried the maven Resource plugin, but that just adds the config file to the resulting shaded jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin) and its [`attach-artifact`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal.

For instance, given the `file.txt` file as part of a maven project and at the same level of its `pom.xml` file, you could have the following pom:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${basedir}/file.txt</file>
                                    <type>txt</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note the configuration of the plugin: basically it is attaching as an additional artifact of the project the `file.txt` file.

One note: as per default artifacts (in this case a `jar`), also additional attached artifacts will follow a naming convention. In this case the `file.txt` file will be renamed to `sample-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.txt` (to make it unique). Its content would not change though.

When installing (`mvn clean install`), you would hence have the following artifacts created:

- `sample-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` > the default project artifact, based on project `packaging`
- `sample-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom` > the `pom.xml` file renamed with `.pom` extension, used by dependency mediation above all to check transitive dependencies in case of libraries
- `sample-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.txt` > the additional attached artifact

Comment: Thanks for the solution. this works well. But is there anyway we can retain the name of txt ??